# IN to test for identity

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a builtin way to do the following in python to test not for equality but for identity:

```
>>> a=1000
>>> b=1000
>>> c=1000
>>> a in [b,c] # test for equality
# True
>>> a is b | a is c
# False
```

Is there a way to do this with `map` or something a bit more compact? Along the lines of:

```
map(is, iterable)
```

With a list comprehension I could do something like:

```
isin=lambda x,L: any([x is l for l in L])
isin(a,[b,c])
# False
```

Comment: `any(a is x for x in [b,c])`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea I think that's the best approach. Is there a way to somehow 'bind' a value into an operator, such as `is(lhs=X, rhs=?)` if that makes sense at all.

Comment: What are you trying to find out here?  Integers are kind of a bad choice for this example, because for SMALL integers and for object, your `a is b` would return true.  For large integers, those are 3 separate objects.  Try it with 7 instead of 1000.

Comment: @TimRoberts right, I'm ignoring the under 8 bit int (or maybe it's implementation/version dependent) just to get an example where it returns `false` on a same-number comparison.

Comment: @David542 you can use a function. `def is_a(x) return x is a` but I don't really see the point

Comment: I just can't see how this is useful for integers.  `a=1000` / `b=a` / `c=a` would give you a different result from `a=1000` / `b=1000` / `c=1000`.  So what?  What have you learned?

Comment: @TimRoberts it's not. I just used integers for an example in the question, though that was probably a poor choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general purpose utility, you can use [`operator.is_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_) to make a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function:

```
from operator import is_
from functools import partial

any(map(partial(is_, a), [b, c]))
```

You can do the same with just a `lambda` of course:

```
any(map(lambda x: a is x, [b, c]))
```

And of course, any `map` can be expressed as a generator:

```
any(a is x for x in [b, c])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)s:

```
id(a) in map(id, [b, c])
```

According to the [`is` operator's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators [is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) and [is not](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) test for an object’s identity:
> `x is y` is true if and only if *x* and *y* are the same object. **An
> Object’s identity is determined using the [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function**.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Small caveat:

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)
> value.

So for example:

```
>>> id([]) in map(id, [[], []])
True
```

Comment: that's pretty neat, I like that solution, thanks!

Comment: This is not as reliable as using `is` in the case of short-lived objects. Consider for example `id([]) in map(id, [[], []])`, that makes a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```py
any(a is x for x in [b, c])
```